# What PostgreSQL query will return unused SEQUENCE #'s?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, sequence

I have enabled a UNIQUE key so PostgreSQL would act as a proof reader for duplicate entries as a bunch of INSERT INTO statements.  Now I need a list of the unused SEQUENCE numbers so I populate these next.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? The only thing a generated unique key needs to be is to be, well, unique. It is completely irrelevant whether that unique value is 1,2,384,-37272, 438238 or 15. You seem to be trying to "solve" a problem that doesn't exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to substitute `mytable` for the table being interrogated and `id` to my preferred `SEQUENCE` variable.

```
SELECT possible FROM GENERATE_SERIES(
  (SELECT MIN(id) FROM mytable), 
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) ) AS possible
LEFT JOIN mytable ON possible = mytable.id 
  WHERE mytable.id IS NULL;
```